# Android UTF-8 cyrillic request

Tags: php, android, json, utf-8, android-volley

In my app i request data from server to show it in user profile view.
App reads JSON data, parses it and pastes in fields of form. There are no problems with charset and app reads cyrillic strings.

I have problem when i try to update my profile:

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://meWebSite.com/userProfile.php?act=edit"
            +"&user_id="+user_id+
            "&country="+country_1.getText().toString()+
            "&city="+city_1.getText().toString(),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            parceEditingJsonRequest(response);
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
```

In this case all cyrillic strings looks like ?????

I printed the request string and pasted it to browser - everything works fine - cyrillic strings were submitted to server properly so i decided that problem is not on server side.

I really don't know where to start from. Maybe i should specify charset for this request?

Comment: charset needs to be specified as UTF-8, and your IDE needs to enable it as well.

Comment: Neither domains nor URLs can contain any non-ASCII characters ... but ... question was asked many times ... there is a solution

Comment: Where is the solution? sorry i don't understand what to do with it - i need full answer

Comment: @LucasCrawford charset of GET ? interesting ...

Comment: try editing your profile page manually using firebug or chrome-inspect and input some cyrillic characters and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html), i.e.:

```
JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://meWebSite.com/userProfile.php?act=edit"
            +"&user_id="+URLEncoder.encode(user_id, "UTF-8")+
            "&country="+URLEncoder.encode(country_1.getText().toString(), "UTF-8")+
            "&city="+URLEncoder.encode(city_1.getText().toString(), "UTF-8"),
```

Then, if you need, on the server side, if you're using php, you can use [utf8_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) or [utf8_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php).

Comment: Thank you! It solved my problem! I also find way to convert strings using escapeJava from org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils